# Laravel: ...layouts.plantilla.blade.php was not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

> ...layouts.plantilla.blade.php was not found.

[image: estructura]

Esta es la estructura que tengo y a pesar de ello no me lo encuentra, estoy con la ultima versión de Laravel

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends("../layouts/plantilla.blade.php")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal la declaración, que por lo que veo buscas colocar la ruta absoluta de donde esta tu archivo .blade, lo cual por cierto no es necesario ya que siempre tratará de encontrar los recursos en:

```
resources/views....
```

Entonces basta con dejarlo asi:

```
@extends("productos.layouts.plantilla")
```

- Por cierto tampoco es necesario colocar la extensión del archivo
- No coloques la diagnonal para indicar niveles, aquí con el . basta

Comment: Es esta la solución, gracias!!

Comment: me faltan 2 min

Comment: Si @wallcroft habia pasado totalmente por alto la carpeta de produtos, entonces cada una separada por . hasta llegar al archivo deseado

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas la directiva `@extends`, esta toma por defecto como carpeta base la carpeta resources/views, por lo cual no es necesario (de hecho es un poco raro hacerlo) utilizar rutas relativas.

Por último, no es necesario agregar las extensiones del archivo, y los `/` pueden reemplazarse con punto `.`

```
@extends('productos.layouts.plantilla')
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error :S que otra cosa podria ser? Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
View [layouts.plantilla] not found. (View: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel_CRUD/resources/views/productos/create.blade.php)

Comment: Solucionado, el problema era que faltaba la carpeta productos.